# Getting error "unable to obtain Microsoftedge using selenium manager" . I am using vb code

Tags: vb.net, selenium-webdriver

I updated the version, I used an older version. This error only occurs in the published version of my project. Here is my code.

```
dim druver as edgedriver
dim win as edgeoptions
dim var as edgedriverserice

win = new edgeoptions
win.addargument_"silent")
var = edgedriverservice.createdefaultservice()
var.hidecommandpromptwindow() = true
driver = new edgedriver(var,win)
```

I think this is the part of the code that I need to change. I am not sure about it or how to go about changing it. I do have the lates version of web driver manager.

Comment: RESOLVED--I was able to resolve this myself. After a lot of digging in my project I came down to a version of one of my packages needed to changed back to an older version.